# SendGrid API 405 Method Not Allowed when trying to send an email

Tags: php, html, email, sendgrid

EDIT 3: This 405 error has something to do with my IIS Express dev environment. I managed to get everything working on my azure web app.

EDIT 2: Duh. I didnt have the environment variable set.

EDIT: I have made some progress thanks to you helpful fellows. Seems I have an authentication problem now even though I am using a fresh API key from SendGrid. I am current getting this error:

```html
401 Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [1] => Server: nginx [2] => Date: Sun, 17 Nov 2019 20:50:16 GMT [3] => Content-Type: application/json [4] => Content-Length: 88 [5] => Connection: keep-alive [6] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io [7] => Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST [8] => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl [9] => Access-Control-Max-Age: 600 [10] => X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html [11] => [12] => ) {"errors":[{"message":"Permission denied, wrong credentials","field":null,"help":null}]}
```

I have a simple button to call a test php file and am working on getting SendGrid for my website.

```html
<form method="post" action="php/send_form_email.php">
                    <input type="submit" value="click on me!">
                </form>
```

Then here is the send_form_email.php file:

```html
<?php

        // You need to install the sendgrid client library so run:     
        // composer require sendgrid/sendgrid
        try
     {
      require 'D:/home/site/wwwroot/vendor/autoload.php';
     }
     catch (Exception $e) {
      echo 'exception' . '<br>';
      var_dump($e);
     }
     
     $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User");
$email->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo("test@example.com", "Example User");
$email->addContent(
    "text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP"
);
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('API_KEY_HERE'));
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
    ?>
```

I installed any composer/sendgrid/curl that I have come across successfully on both my machine and my azure web app.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the library version you are using? And at which step exactly to you get the error ?

Comment: I am using version 7.3 of the library. If I could figure some way to debug to figure out what step I was on then that would really help. Wish fiddler worked on this website or that I could figure out how to get an alert working so I could see how far into the code I get. At this point I've tried to really simplify the code and get anything at all to work.

Comment: Where are you hosting this PHP file?

Comment: This is all hosted on an azure web app. Locally I get the 405 error. When I post this to azure and run the site as normal I get a 500 error. Right now I would be happy if either one worked so I could at least know my code is right.

Comment: How are you running the app locally? What sort of webserver? The 500 is a separate issue you should debug by looking at the info in the logs.

Comment: Locally I am just running it using IIS express.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution but help for debug:

Replace:

```
$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);

if ($response->statusCode() == 202) {
 // Successfully sent
 echo 'done';
} else {
 echo 'false';
}
```

By

```
try {
    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
    if ($response->statusCode() == 202) {
       echo 'done';
    } else {

        echo 'false' . '<br>';
        var_dump($response);

    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'exception' . '<br>';
    var_dump($e);

}
```

Then post the results here.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. I am so frustrated by this point. I get the same error:  HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

Comment: You get only this message when u click on your button ? not echoing 'false' or anything else ?? try to put a `die('ok');` after `$sg = new \SendGrid($API_KEY);` and show result

Comment: Did as you asked and I still get the 405 error. No messages of any kind before. However, I do notice on my published version of the app I am getting echo messages until I get to require '/vendor/autoload.php'; then nothing after. No errors of any kind displayed.

Comment: Be more specific, which echo is displayed ? In this case put the die, just after the require line and do you still have 405 ?

Comment: ONLY a 405 error when I run locally. Sorry to confuse with the echo - I only get an echo when I publish the site and try on the webserver. I shouldn't be mixing two different problems here. Locally when I run I just get the 405 error no matter what I do to my php page.

Comment: if locally you have 405 and on webserver and echo , it could be a misconfiguration on your local server. When you are on your webserver, does it echo done or false ?

Comment: The webserver will do any echo messages until I get to require '/vendor/autoload.php'; then nothing after. No errors of any kind displayed.

Comment: Can you call : send_form_email.php directly, without using the button and tell what  you are getting?

Comment: OK. I see an error finally --- int(2) string(79) "require(/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory" string(44) "D:\home\site\wwwroot\php\send_form_email.php" int(13) array(4) { ["_GET"]=> array(0) { } ["_POST"]=> array(0) { } ["_COOKIE"]=> array(1) { ["ARRAffinity"]=> string(64) "366ef1906eda232dd4fa18f32e0793800c765d26b4da9643746011451b789a58" } ["_FILES"]=> array(0) { } } Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\home\site\wwwroot\php\send_form_email.php on line 13

Comment: I should add I do have a file at ~wwwroot/vendor/autoload.php which was generated by composer

Comment: Getting closer I think. I put in the absolute path to the autoload.php file and now got down to this error:   Fatal error: Class 'SendGrid\Email' not found in D:\home\site\wwwroot\php\send_form_email.php on line 32

Answer (score -1):

The code that I edited in my original post now works. The main thing was the php debugging needed to be turned on and then I started getting real errors. Make sure this is at the top of the php file so you can get error reporting.

PHP Code:

```html
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");
```